# how to create a function that takes ANY number and finds the LARGEST number formed by consecutive digits in that number

Tags: javascript

how to create a function that takes ANY number and finds the LARGEST number formed by consecutive digits in that number in Javascript ?

example:
input: 90123609789
output: 90123

input: 53590 output 90
input:674030098567819 output: 5678

Comment: If you need help with a math problem try the math stack exchange site.

Comment: Can you explain why output must be `90123` and not `609789`? Basically number itself is _largest_ number formed by consecutive digits in that number

Comment: because I need a largest sequencial/consecutive number example: 53590 output 90
674030098567819 output: 5678
9012364509789. output: 90123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try all substrings where the difference between adjacent digits is 1 under modulus 10.

```js
function largestConsecutiveDigits(n) {
  let str = String(n),
    res = Math.max(...str);
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < str.length; j++) {
      if ((str[j] - str[j - 1] + 10) % 10 === 1) 
        res = Math.max(res, str.slice(i, j + 1));
      else break;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(largestConsecutiveDigits('90123609789'));
console.log(largestConsecutiveDigits('53590'));
```